# Canvas in a javascript class

Tags: javascript, class, canvas

I'm trying to add an element into a canvas, everything managed by a class:
I made a class that controls the size of the canvas and a second class that should display an element on the same canvas.

```js
class CanvasGame {
  constructor() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("game");
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.height = window.innerHeight;
  }
}

class Tanks extends CanvasGame {
  constructor(ctx) {
    super(ctx);
    this.tankWidth = 45;
    this.tankhHeight = 35;
    this.angle = "angle";
    this.power = "power";
    this.colors = ["purple", "red", "yellow", "green"];
    this.startPosXp1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.width + 0);
    this.startPosYp1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.height + 0);
  }

  colorSelection() {
    return this.colors[0];
  }

  tank1() {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.colorSelection();
    this.ctx.fillRect(this.width, this.height, this.startPosXp1, this.startPosYp1);
  }
}

let core = new CanvasGame();
let player1 = new Tanks();

player1.tank1();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#game {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="game"></canvas>
  <script src="src/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I actually do not get why it does not display anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 2 parameters of `fillRect` are the top left x & y co-ords.
You had set them to be the height & width of the whole canvas (`ctx`) so the tank was drawing, but its top left point was drawn at the visible canvas's bottom right corner!

See [This](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fillrect.asp) page for more information on canvas, and good luck with the game!

Give @muzzletov a point as well since he has a valid statement about creating the canvas twice. You don't need to as 'Tank' Class already creates a canvas

```js
class CanvasGame {
  constructor() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("game");
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.height = window.innerHeight;
  }
}

class Tanks extends CanvasGame {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.tankWidth = 45;
    this.tankhHeight = 35;
    this.angle = "angle";
    this.power = "power";
    this.colors = ["purple", "red", "yellow", "green"];
    this.startPosXp1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.width + 0);
    this.startPosYp1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.height + 0);
  }

  colorSelection() {
    return this.colors[0];
  }

  tank1() {

    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.colorSelection();
    //this.ctx.fillRect(this.height, this.width,this.startPosXp1, this.startPosYp1);
    this.ctx.fillRect(0,0, this.startPosXp1, this.startPosYp1);
  }
}

//let core = new CanvasGame();
let player1 = new Tanks();

player1.tank1();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#game {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="game"></canvas>
  <script src="src/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you, really i didn't know this! and about the position error actually i deleted the startPosY1 for error so thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the parameters for fillRect - it's `fillRect(x, y, width, height)` not `fillRect(width, height, x, y)`. Also, you do not need to instantiate the parent twice.
Just create a Tank object.

Answer (score 0):

You've got several issues in your code. You are setting the x/y with the width/height, but you're also not using the correct width and height values.

You need to use the tank's width and height when rendering it.

```js
class CanvasGame {
  constructor() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("game");
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.height = window.innerHeight;
  }
}

class Tanks extends CanvasGame {
  constructor(ctx) {
    super(ctx);
    this.tankWidth = 45;
    this.tankHeight = 35;
    this.angle = "angle";
    this.power = "power";
    this.colors = ["purple", "red", "yellow", "green"];
    this.startPosXp1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.tankWidth + 0);
    this.startPosYp1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.tankHeight + 0);
  }

  colorSelection() {
    return this.colors[0];
  }

  tank1() {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.colorSelection();
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.tankWidth, this.tankHeight);
  }
}

let core = new CanvasGame();
let player1 = new Tanks(core.ctx);

player1.tank1();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#game {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="game"></canvas>
  <script src="src/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```